# Save Konva canvas as image on Cordova-Phonegap

Tags: cordova, html5-canvas, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, konvajs

I'd like to be able to save the Konva canvas to user's device on an app built using Cordova. So far, all the plugins I've used fail to do the task required as they seem to be unable to handle the base64 address I get from the DataURL. So far tried the Canvas2Image plugin, Cordova Base64 plugin and others. 
It's possible i'm doing this the wrong way.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Ash - there is not enough detail in your question to get anything but glib answers. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Thanks, will edit.